# Wordpress Changing the default redirect when wrong password

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a wordpress template and added a login form to in via code:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="20" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
    <p>
        <label for="rememberme">
        <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me
    </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
```

It works fine but when anyone insert the wrong password it goes the wp-login.php page. I would like to change that and point it to go to my template url instead.

The question is...where do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to add a filter to login_redirect in your functions file

Have you seen this http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Answer (score 6):

Customizing the Login Form page is not enough: when login fails due to an incorrect password, the standard wp-login.php page shows up.

I managed to redirect to my custom Login Form page by adding this to `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'redirect_login_failed');
function redirect_login_failed() {
    wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url') . '/?myLoginFormPage&login=failed' );
}
```